# How to implement reference hyperlinks without displaying doi

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

I would like to implement the following reference style, which can be clicked and then jump to the corresponding DOI website, I use the bibtex reference file, I want to implement the references shown below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should show us a short compilable tex code building your bibliography and do not forget to add two used bib entries to your question!

Comment: IIRC, \href and \url are the only way to link web addresses.  See also \hyperbaseurl regarding path names.